# Can a Kafka Connector load its own name?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

According to Kafka Documentation

> Connector configurations are simple key-value mappings. For standalone
>   mode these are defined in a properties file and passed to the Connect
>   process on the command line.
>
> Most configurations are connector dependent, so they can't be outlined
>   here. However, there are a few common options:
>
> ```
> name - Unique name for the connector. Attempting to register again with the same name will fail.
> ```

I have 10 connectors running in standalone mode like this:

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties connector1.properties connector2.properties ...
```

**My question is can a connector load its own name at runtime?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get the name of the connector at runtime.

When connector starts all properties are passed to `Connector::start(Map<String, String> props)`. Connector can read those properties, validate them, save and later pass to `Task`. It depends on Connector implementation if he use it or not.

Connector name property is `name`.

Comment: Thanks they are loaded via properties argument of "public void start(Map<String, String> props)" method of the connector task.